# Problem in calculating angles of a tringle with co-ordinate geometry

Tags: coordinate-systems

There are three equations.

$$(a+b)x+(a-b)y-2ab = 0 \tag1$$
$$(a-b)x+(a+b)y-2ab = 0 \tag2$$
$$x+y = 0 \tag3$$

The question is,

1. So that the triangle formed by these equations is an isosceles triangle.
2. Show that the angle between the two equal sides of the triangle is $2\tan^{-1}\frac ab$.

**What I did:**

**Part 1.**

I could solve (1) and (3) and then (2) and (3) and then calculate two sides of the triangle and show they are equal but that would require much calculations.

So I took a different strategy: Calculate the angle between 1 and 3 and then 1 and 2 and show them to be equal.

But the angle between (1) and (3) is $\tan^{-1}(\pm\frac ba)$ (calculated using gradients of (1) and (3))

And, the angle between (2) and (3) is $\tan^{-1}(\mp\frac ba)$

Which sign should I consider? There will be many cases if different types of values for a and b are taken.

**Part 2.**

And the angle between (1) and (2) is,

$$\tan^{-1}\left[\pm \frac{\displaystyle\frac{2a}b}{1-\displaystyle\frac{a^2}{b^2}}\right]=2\tan^{-1}\frac ab\text{ or }\pi-2\tan^{-1}\frac ab$$

So I could not calculate one value. How to know which of this two angles is inside the triangle?

Comment: That wouldn't really require as much calculation as it seems. You should try it.

Comment: What is the value of $\arctan(\pm\frac ba)+\arctan(-(\pm\frac ba))$?  Recall that $\sin x$ is odd while $\cos x$ is even...

Comment: Here are the vertices $(a,-a) , (-a,a) ( b,b) $

Comment: @Mann Yeah but I cannot calculate all the angles that way (part 2), so calculating angles is the time saving method. Moreover, I want to know how to do this this way.

Comment: Well the triangle is essentially isoceles on the point $(b,b)$ so it's just you have to calculate the angle in between it.

Comment: Here's a hint: What is $\tan^{-1} \frac{2ab}{b^2-a^2}$ , use the vertices i gave you , to find slope and angle.

Comment: @abiessu Is it $\\pi$? I cannot understand what you said about $\sin x $ and $\\cos x$

Comment: @Mann Sorry, I think it should be $\ 2tan^-1\frac ab$ or, $\ \pi-\ 2tan^-1\frac ab$

Comment: You have to choose the acute value, + value corresponds to acute angle and - to obtuse usually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23664/discussion-between-mann-and-archisman-panigrahi).